# Can I request a post value as the directory string when uploading files?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, post

I would like to change the upload directory depending on a hidden value in form submission.

As you can see I have a POST after move_uploaded_file that is submitted on the form but it fails to upload if I add the directory location. The directory has been created to the POST value prior to this. Thank you

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['myusername'] == 'admin')  
  { 
 $header = 'headeradmin.php';
  }
 elseif (!empty($_SESSION['myusername']))
 {
 $header = 'header.php';
 }
 else
  {header("location:../../login");}

require_once '../../connect.php';

$loggedin= $_SESSION['myusername'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");
if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_GET['id'];


?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Image upload</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="../../custom.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif",     // Valid file formats
    form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
    dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
    uploadUrl: "upload.php"             // Server side upload url
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    initMultiUploader(config);
});
</script>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body lang="en">

<div id="content">

<?php require_once $header;

$sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE `id` = $id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
  {
$username = $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'];

if (!file_exists('uploads/' . $username )) {
    mkdir('uploads/' . $username, 0777, true);
}
  }

 ?>
<h1 class="title">Multiple Drag and Drop File Upload</h1>
<div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
    <h1>Drop Images Here</h1>
</div>
<form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name="username" id="username"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />
</form>
<div class="progressBar">
    <div class="status"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is where the form is redirected, I have now removed the echo but it does not seem to work.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_POST['username'] . '/' .$_FILES['file']['name'])){
        echo($_POST['index']);
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're not 100% aware of the security implications of what you are asking, [Please read this.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload)  You are basically opening your server up for an easy takeover if you are allowing uploads to any location.  If you are aware and have addressed them via other controls, that's OK.  I have no idea what your secure coding knowledge/experience level is, I'm just passing this along because it looks dangerous to me.

Comment: Also relevant: [Path Traversal vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) (although with this design, there's no real need to traverse paths.)

Comment: Prior to this i have a session and only admin can login to upload files, if its not the correct password/username then they get kicked. I will include security but if I add to this code the upload seems to stop working. I will add the form to show whats happening thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all this code is that this code is not very secure. User can write there anything.
Second don't use echo in functions. Just $_POST['username'].

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove echo

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_POST['username'] . '/' .$_FILES['file']['name'])){
```

I would also suggest not using `$_POST['username']` but instead use `$_SESSION['username']` unless I am missing something and you are allowing users to upload files into other users directories

Comment: the admin will be signed in but the admin will be allowed only to add files to another client account